# how to delete a comment in javascript and ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to write a simple delete function for a comment system that i am working on. the comments are stored in a database where each comment has a cid that is incremented automatically. i have noticed that the user can only delete the first comment he/she has written but when a the user writes two comments and presses delete on the second one, the comment can not be deleted, can someone help fix this. here is my code. thank you for your help.

this is my meatballs.php file where i have the comments loaded.

```
<div class = "page" id = "comments">
  <p class = "style">Comments</p>
  <button class="btn" id="load-comments">See Previous Comments</button><br> 
  <br>

  <?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['u_id'])){
          echo "  <input type = 'hidden' id = 'uid' value = '".$_SESSION['u_uid']."'>
          <input type = 'hidden' id = 'date' value = '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
          <textarea id = 'message'></textarea><br>
          <button class = 'btn' type = 'submit' id = 'meatballsSubmit'>Comment</button>";
      }
     else{
          echo "<p>Please log in to comment</p>";}
  ?>

</div><br>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#load-comments").click(function(){
           document.getElementById('#comments').innerHTML=
               $("#comments").load("getComments.php");
       });
   });
</script>
```

as for getCommetns.php file which retrieves the comments from the database.

```
<?php

include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
session_start();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM meatballscomments";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  echo "<div class = 'comment-box'>";
  echo '<span class = "user">'.$row['user_uid'].'</span><br><br>';
  echo "<p>".htmlspecialchars($row['message'])."</p>";
  echo '<span class = "datef">'.$row['date'].'</span>';

  if(isset($_SESSION['u_id']) && $_SESSION['u_uid'] == $row['user_uid']){
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' id = 'cid' value = '".$row['cid']."'>";
    echo "<button class = 'btn' type = 'submit' id = 'meatballsDelete'>Delete</button>";
    }
   echo "</div><hr>";
   }
?>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#meatballsDelete").click(function(){
            var cid = $("#cid").val();
            $.ajax({
            url: "deleteComment.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {
                "cid": cid
            }});
        alert("Your comment has been deleted");
        });
    });
</script>
```

the deleteComment.php file that i have is very short and here it is.

```
<?php
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
$cid = $_POST['cid'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM meatballscomments WHERE cid = '$cid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Because `id` attribute __must be unique__ on the page.

Comment: i actually used an ajax function instead and sent the comment id as an argument. i  thought it would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['u_id']) && $_SESSION['u_uid'] == $row['user_uid']){
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<p id='demo'></p>";
    $commentId = $row['cid'];
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' id = 'cid' value = '".$row['cid']."'>";
    echo "<button class = 'btn' type = 'submit'  onclick= 'deleteFunction($commentId, 1)'>Delete</button>";
  }
```

and the script i used

```
<script>
  function deleteFunction(cid, page){
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cid + " ----"+ page;
    $.ajax({
      url: "deleteComment.php",
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      data: {
        "cid": cid,
        "page": page}
    });
    alert("Your comment has been deleted!");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: i also added $pageNo = $_POST['page']; in deleteComment.php file to just to select the table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the same `id` on multiple html elements & using `val()` on the result of the jQuery selector which returns the first element with the id of `cid`. From [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID
>   will only select the first matched element in the DOM.

Therefore there's no guarantee that it automatically grabs the right element for you, when you're using the same `id` multiple times.

**The quickest fix** would be to change `#meatballsDelete` to `.meatballsDelete`, and add the `meatballsDelete` class to your button, that way clicking will register on both buttons. Also add the `$row['cid']` value as attribute to the button and then grab that with `$(this).attr("myAttribute")` in the function in  `click`, which will always guarantee that the id is returned which belongs to the button.

Like @u_mulder says in the comments, you're also using an `id` to register the click, which will also bind to the first element with that id.

Comment: `#id` selector returns __one__ element and `val` works correctly.

Comment: `$("#meatballsDelete").click` will be binded to first item only.

Comment: ok thank you guys for the clarification :)  but is there an easy way to fix this or do i have to redo the whole thing?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonably easy way to modify your code to resolve this issue would be to get rid of the hidden `cid` input and add the `cid` value as a data value to your button. You also need to change the button to have a class `meatballsDelete` rather than an id, since `id` values must be unique. So change this:

```
echo "<input type = 'hidden' id = 'cid' value = '".$row['cid']."'>";
echo "<button class = 'btn' type = 'submit' id = 'meatballsDelete'>Delete</button>";
```

To

```
echo "<button class = 'btn meatballsDelete' type = 'submit' data-cid = '{$row['cid']}'>Delete</button>";
```

and then modify your javascript to add the click handler to items of class `meatballsDelete` (instead of id) and retrieve the `cid` value from the data-cid attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".meatballsDelete").click(function(){
        var cid = $(this).data('cid');
        $.ajax({
            url: "deleteComment.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {
                "cid": cid
        }});
        alert("Your comment has been deleted");
    });
});
```